# Kubernetes 1.6 on Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

According to [this blog post](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/04/Google-Container-Engine-fires-up-Kubernetes-1-6.html) Kubernetes 1.6 should be available on Google Container Engine:

> Today we started to make Kubernetes 1.6 available to Google Container
>   Engine customers.

But how do I enable it? The gcloud seems to think only 1.5.6 is available:

```
$ gcloud container get-server-config --zone us-central1-a
Fetching server config for us-central1-a
defaultClusterVersion: 1.5.6
defaultImageType: COS
validImageTypes:
- CONTAINER_VM
- COS
validMasterVersions:
- 1.5.6
validNodeVersions:
- 1.5.6
- 1.5.4
- 1.4.9
- 1.4.8
- 1.3.10
- 1.2.7


$ gcloud container get-server-config --zone europe-west1-d
Fetching server config for europe-west1-d
defaultClusterVersion: 1.5.6
defaultImageType: COS
validImageTypes:
- COS
- CONTAINER_VM
validMasterVersions:
- 1.5.6
validNodeVersions:
- 1.5.6
- 1.5.4
- 1.4.9
- 1.4.8
- 1.3.10
- 1.2.7
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Container Engine release notes for April 4, 2017](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/release-notes#april_4_2017) describe when 1.6.0 will be available in each zone.

us-central1-a and europe-west1-d both happened to be scheduled for the final day which is Friday April 7th.